# Use custom image to replace the check mark while tableview is being multiple selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I tried to replace the check mark with a custom image. I used the method as below:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIControl *control in self.subviews){
        if ([control isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITableViewCellEditControl")]){
            for (UIView *v in control.subviews)
            {
                if ([v isKindOfClass: [UIImageView class]]) {
                    UIImageView *img=(UIImageView *)v;
                    if (self.selected) {
                        img.image= [UIImage createImageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]];
                    }else
                    {
                        img.image= [UIImage createImageWithColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It does work fine even though there's still a problem.  There are no `UIControl` in `self.subviews` at the beginning.

[image]

As the picture showed. the check marks did not being replaced by the yellow image until I click on them.

Comment: Why not simply subclassing `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Oh.It is a subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: Well, then override `-[UITableViewCell setSelected:animated]` and update your imageView

Comment: well.It's not working. What I am trying to do is to replace the check mark while the tableview is multiple selected. And I have to use the for in method to get the check mark image view, so that I can replace it  with a custom image.  But the for in method is not working at the very beginning when the time I set the table View to multiple selected.

Comment: It's no wonder. These UI Hacks usually don't work or just for some time and they aren't edgecase proof at all. Simply do it the right way. Don't loop them, set the correct image in the appropriate method. This also prevents your app from dealing with the SDK in a completely unexpected manner. There are APIs for that. Read the docs. Use the SDK as Apple expects you to.

Comment: I understand. But , I can not find any APIs that I could use to replace the check mark Image.  The loop method, It seems is the only way I could do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call -setImageForCheckMark both in -layoutSubviews and -didTransitionToState. -didTransitionToState for the changing of cell state,-layoutSubviews for the changing of your click state

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    // well ,while you change your cells' state into EditState ,-layoutSubviews will be invoked.
    // but the _imageView of control always be nil at end of layoutSubviews
    // I've try KVO to observe this _imageView ,but obviously it's not an attribute
    // Thankfully, UITableViewCell provide us with -willTransitionToState/-didTransitionToState
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setImageForCheckMark];
}


- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state{
    // you should override it by your subclass ,when this method get called
    // all details of cell will be completed
    if (UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask) {
        [self setImageForCheckMark];
    }
}

- (void)setImageForCheckMark{
    for (UIControl *control in self.subviews){
        if ([control isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITableViewCellEditControl")]){
            UIImageView *image = [control valueForKey:@"_imageView"];
            imageView.image = [UIImage createImageWithColor:self.selected?[UIColor yellowColor]:[UIColor greenColor]];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work on swift 4 and 5.

I am using the xcode system images so don't need to replace the image  when running this code

```
// Add this to your Table View Controller

// Step 1

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.imageView?.image == UIImage(systemName:"checkmark.circle")) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName:"circle")
    } else {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName:"checkmark.circle")
    }
}

//Step 2

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = employeeValues[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName:"circle")

    return cell
}
```